# Accessing Variables from try{} catch{}

Tags: c#, try-catch, scope

I am attempting to access a variable (specifically an ArrayList) after a try{} catch{} method.

```
try 
{
//Here I would import data from an ArrayList if it was already created.
}
catch
{  
//Create new array list if it couldn't find one.
ArrayList items = new ArrayList();
}
```

One way or another, the ArrayList items will be created and I want to be able to access it. I tried to initialize the ArrayList before, like so:

```
ArrayList items;
try 
{
//Here I would import data from an ArrayList if it was already created.
}
catch
{  
//Create new array list if it couldn't find one.
ArrayList items = new ArrayList();
}
```

But then I can't do anything with in the try{} catch{} blocks because it says' it's already been created.

I want to be able to create a program that remembers the actions from the time it was run before, but I just can't seem to get my ahead around the right concepts.

Comment: Just remove 'ArrayList' from the Catch block

Comment: FYI, unless you're using .NET 2.0, you should not be using `ArrayList`. You should use `List<T>` instead.

Comment: I recommend you to use List<T> instead of ArrayList

Comment: `List<T>` is in .NET 2.0... He would have to be the only person in the world still using .NET 1.1.

Comment: Side note: There is no need for "I'm new here", "googled a lot", "thank you notes" in the post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to move the scope outwards:

```
ArrayList items;    // do not initialize
try 
{
   //Here I would import data from an ArrayList if it was already created.
   items = ...;
}
catch
{  
  //Create new array list if it couldn't find one.
  items = new ArrayList();  // note no re-declaration, just an assignment
}
```

But let me give you a few tips:

- don't invest too much in `ArrayList()`, look at `List<T>` instead.
- be very careful about how you use `catch {}`.
  Something went (very) wrong, providing a default answer is usually not the right policy.

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you so very much for your help. Setting the ArrayList to null, and then just adjusting the 'items' ArrayList in the try{} catch{} block worked out perfectly!

    ArrayList items = null;
I think you forgot to remove the ; after items. Thanks.

Comment: It's better not to use `= null;` here, it will only mask errors (forgetting to set it in the right places). The 'unassigned variable' error is a friend, not an enemy.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to recreate the items variable, just instantiate it.

```
ArrayList items;
try 
{
    //Here I would import data from an ArrayList if it was already created.
}
catch
{  
    //Create new array list if it couldn't find one.
    items = new ArrayList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ArrayList items;

try 
{
   //Here I would import data from an ArrayList if it was already created.
}
catch
{  
   //Create new array list if it couldn't find one.
   items = new ArrayList();
}
```